# How do we add custom properties to a google drive file(PDF) using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

```
function addCustomProperty(fileId) {
  var property = {
    key: 'department',
    value: 'Sales',
    visibility: 'PUBLIC'
  };
  Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please add more details like the steps you follow to prepare your Apps Script project and how are you running the function .

Comment: Crossposted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59466195/1595451

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was also posted in [so] and cross-posting isn't allowed across [se] sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppScript to insert our own custom properties to a specific file in Google drive

```
function addCustomProperty(fileId) { 
 var fileId="1DrB95-HB7DEyqHx3oXceZZcT8mOcTsu5";
  var property =  {
                    key: 'newrelease',
                    value: 'PDF2020', 
                    visibility: 'PUBLIC' 
                  }; 

  Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
  Logger.log(fileId);
  Logger.log(property);
}
```

In the code given above, must specify your file id `fileId` and `visibilty` must be `PUBLIC`, must enable *Drive API* in the resources section.